# SQL - check for existence of data within each day of a dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset using Google BigQuery, for a date range. The data is like this:

```
id   date         value1   value2
--   ---------    ------   ------
1    01-feb-2019  1        2
2    01-feb-2019  2        2
3    02-feb-2019  1        2
4    02-feb-2019  2        2
```

I want to check for the existence of a record on each particular day that matches a specified rule, and to return a 'status' for that day based on that rule being met.  So for example my rule could be to return a status of `1` for the day if there is any record for that day where `value1 = 1` and `value2 = 2`

My final result set for the above data would look like this:

```
date            status
----            ------
01-feb-2019     1
02-feb-2019     1
```

I also want to check a *2nd* and *3rd* rule for each day, and return different status codes if these other rules are met. How can I do that in a single SQL query (I don't mind sub-selects etc.).

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
select date,
       (case when sum(case when value1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when value2 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
             then 1 else 0
        end) as status
from t
group by date;
```

Comment: just a little fix: the first value is value1 and second one is value2

Answer (score 0):

So I add for Rule 1 and if you want to add more rule just add more `WHEN , THEN` and so on ...

```
select *
from (select date,
             (case
                when value1 = 1 AND value2 = 2 then 1 -- Rule1
             -- when value1 = .. AND value2 = .. then .. -- Rule2
             -- when value1 = ... AND value2 = ... then ... -- Rule3
                else 0
               end) as status
      from test
      group by date, status) as test
where status > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the approach from @Gordon Linoff. To get the extra rules I use nested case statements. In my case, the 3rd rule applies if the first 2 rules aren't met, so I do this:

```
select date,
       (case when sum(case when value1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when value2 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
             then 2 -- 1st rule applies
        else
          case when sum(case when value1 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when value2 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
             then 1 -- 2nd rule applies
             else
                  0 -- 3rd rule applies
             end
        end) as status
from t
group by date;
```